# show pdf icon in email instead of pdf image - iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, email

I have created a pdf file and attached it in the email. It shows the complete PDF file as image in email composer.

[image: sample image]

I just want to show the icon of pdf file instead of complete pdf file. Like this:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.

It might be the way the iPhone renders the email and attachments. At first it shows the icon because its loading the pdf or attachment file then eventually it will show the attached file. Anyone else disagree?

Comment: no it never shows the pdf file in attachment it only shows the icon.